# Bootstrap modal moves unexpectedly on 2nd click

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, modal-dialog, css-position, offset

Sorry for the title gore, wasn't sure how to be more concise.

**What I'm trying to do:**

I have a modal that I want to be called from multiple buttons (dynamically created) and positioned near the buttons.  With jQuery, I'm getting the `.offset()` of the clicked button then assigning it to the modal.

**Bootply:** http://www.bootply.com/lEUtR2IkeU

**The JS:**

```
$('.model-open-btn').click(function(){
  $('#pageJumpModal').show().height( '1px' ); //#pageJumpModal is the container that's hidden, .offset has problems with hidden elements, so show it first.
  var offset = $(this).offset();  //Get the button's offset
  $('#pageJumpModal > .modal-dialog').offset({top: offset.top, left: offset.left}); //Set the modal's position.
  $('#pageJumpModal').height( 'auto' ).hide(); //Reset the container's height.
});
```

**The problem:**

The first time either button is clicked, it works fine (well, I'd rather it show above, but good enough for now), but the 2nd time the modal is show then it's top position is increased by 13px.

I'm sure there's something I'm not considering,but I'm lost.  I tried .position(), just getting/setting the css top and left attributes, and many other things.  Time to turn to smarter minds than mine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the issue was the `position: absolute;` for the `.modal-dialog` and that it was inside the container.  Modals should basically be at the end of the `<body>` so their position will be relative to the document and nothing else.

Here's the solution: http://www.bootply.com/AkdX5Cqw9D

IMO, this is a much better alternative for anyone that has a bunch of dropdowns/menus that do similar things.  I set values or anything I want to change about the modal in the `data-...` attributes of the calling button, then pass the values in a `$.click()` (which could also be done using Bootstrap's Modal events).

Answer (score 1):

try  add height & top position to modal box

**CSS**

```
#pageJumpModal>.modal-dialog {
  position: absolute;
      width: 160px;
      height:160px;
      top:50px !important;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://www.bootply.com/1PqUpUz24q)

I hope this helps

Comment: I figuered it out.  Perhaps I wasn't clear enough in my questions, but I wanted the modal to appear near the button that triggered it.  Your answer would had it appear at the same height regardless of what button was selected.  Thanks for trying to help though!